# How to increase jenkins logger size?

Tags: jenkins, logging

I use Jenkins log recorders as described in docs:
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/system-administration/viewing-logs/
It works, but log is only about 255 lines long, which is too short for my processing.
Newest lines are shown, I cant reach older logs, so I dont know what happened in the beginning.
How do I increase this size? I would like to keep at least 1MB of data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this [Jenkins system property](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/system-properties/#hudson-util-ringbufferloghandler-defaultsize) will do the trick:

> ```
> hudson.util.RingBufferLogHandler.defaultSize
> ```
>
> tuning
>
> Since: 1.563
>
> Default:  256
>
> **Description:** Number of log entries in loggers available on the UI at /log/

You can also custom [Configure Loggers for Jenkins](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002626172-Configure-Loggers-for-Jenkins) or [create a logger in Jenkins for troubleshooting and diagnostic information](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/204880580-How-do-I-create-a-logger-in-Jenkins-for-troubleshooting-and-diagnostic-information-) that capture specifics you are looking for.

Additional references:
[JENKINS - Logging](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Logging)
[JENKINS - Logger Configuration](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Logger+Configuration)

Or, if you are the admin, you should be able simply to scan the logs on the filesystem. Review what log rotation options and retention you may have.

Comment: If you're using Helm: `controller: javaOpts: - "-Dhudson.util.RingBufferLogHandler.defaultSize=4096"